# How to get information about HTTP request down the stack of the Spring framework handler method

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to get information about HTTP request from the method down the callstack of the Spring request handler method?

In other words given I have a handler method like:

```java
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
  MyInternalClass.doSomeAction();
  return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

I am looking for means to get the information about HTTP request (such as URL, headers, etc.) within the code of the `doSomeAction()` static method in the `MyInternalClass` class.

The constraint is that I **cannot** modify the original method (`hello()`).

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Request parameter of type `HttpServletRequest`

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(
   @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name,
   HttpServletRequest originalRequest) {
  // HERE: call another method here
  return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

Have a look at the [Spring Reference Documentation, Chapter "Method Arguments"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

---

Part 2

> However, I was looking for a method that does not force developers to change their code. I will try to add an example to my question, so it will be more verbose.

You can use the [`RequestContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to get the request attributes.

```
HttpServletRequest request = 
      ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
```

`RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` is a static method, that can be invoked from every where (even for a class that is no Spring Bean). But it is required that it is invoked from a thread that was triggert by a HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you, @Ralph. However, I was looking for a method that does not force developers to change their code.
I will try to add an example to my question, so it will be more verbose.

Comment: @LeoY see part two of may anser